# Parse JSON Array without Key

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to parse the `jsonArray` but unable to understand this format,How to parse this type of `jsonArray`?
Can anyone help me?

```
  "rows": [
                [
                    "/farmfresh",
                    "20171211",
                    "4"
                ],
                [
                    "/farmfresh/product/d",
                    "20171215",
                    "4"
                ],
                [
                    "/farmfresh/product/h",
                    "20171222",
                    "2"
                ]
            ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
try 
{    
    JSONObject resObject = new JSONObject("your json response");    
    JSONArray jsonArray = resObject.getJSONArray("rows");        

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {        
       JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);

       for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {

          Log.i("Value","->" +jsonArray1.getString(j));
       }
   }

} 
catch (JSONException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the structure.**

```
Object

  rows->Array

     -Array
     -Array
     -Array
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, we cannot parse the JSON you shared. It always has to start with "{" or "[". If it is an array it should look like below JSON

```
["rows": [
            [
                "/farmfresh",
                "20171211",
                "4"
            ],
            [
                "/farmfresh/product/d",
                "20171215",
                "4"
            ],
            [
                "/farmfresh/product/h",
                "20171222",
                "2"
            ]
        ]
]
```

Comment: maybe you can add "{" or "[" at beginning and end. And then parse it, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your JSON data is not valid. The valid data will be

```
 { "rows": [
            [
                "/farmfresh",
                "20171211",
                "4"
            ],
            [
                "/farmfresh/product/d",
                "20171215",
                "4"
            ],
            [
                "/farmfresh/product/h",
                "20171222",
                "2"
            ]
        ]
}
```

Now we can parse this valid json as give below. This is for android using default JSON parse. Here you

```
void parseJsonString(String jsonString) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Log.d("jsonParse", "row position    =   " + String.valueOf(i));
            JSONArray jsonRow = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonRow.length(); j++) {
                String value = jsonRow.get(j).toString();
                Log.d("jsonParse", "value at " + String.valueOf(j) + " position is  " + value);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code is done for android. Here the JSON String is passed as the argument of the `parseJsonString` method. It will print the values in logcat as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
String data = "{"+"YOUR_DATA"+"}";
 try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray itemArray = object.getJSONArray("rows");
        for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray innerItemArray=  itemArray.getJSONArray(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < innerItemArray.length(); j++) {
                String value=innerItemArray.getString(j);
                Log.e("json", "="+value);
            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope it helps..