# How to convert an json response like that?

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a json reponse like given below.Basically,I want to convert an object and use it.

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1290,
        "N": "Türkiye",
        "Fid": 196,
        "EC": 10,
        "CL": null,
        "SID": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 1239,
        "N": "Dünya",
        "Fid": 152,
        "EC": 63,
        "CL": null,
        "SID": 0
    }
]
 ... Goes on
```

Here is what I have tried,I am using org.json library.

```
String jsonString = response.body().string(); // Getting json response and converting to string.
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject( jsonString ); // Not working
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray( jsonString ); // Not working
JSONArray matches = new JSONArray( jsonString ).getJSONArray(0); // Not working
```

But I am gettin those errors

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 0 [character 1 line 1]
A JSONArray text must begin with '{' at 0 [character 1 line 1]
```

I have checked topics like [Parse JSON Array without Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003012/parse-json-array-without-key). But the json described not like mine.

Any idea what should ı do?

Comment: Actually, your title doesn't summarize your question.

Answer (score 0):

in Java you would first need to define a class which has all the attributes

```
public class MyClass {
    private int Id;
    private int N;
    private int Fid;
    private int EC;
    private int CL;
    private int Sid;

// getters, setters, no arg constructor
}
```

then you can use for example [gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) library to parse it like this:

`MyClass[] myClassArray = gson.fromJson(jsonString , MyClass[].class)`

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you to use the Gson library it's way better to perform data operations:

```
public class User {
    int id;
    String n;
    int fid;
    int ec;
    String cl;
    int sid;

    public static User[] parse(String s){
        return new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(s, User[].class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Google's Gson? It is really easy to use and you can both serialize and deserialize objects.

Here is an example:

```
    public Company[] deserializeCompany() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Company[] companies = gson.fromJson(companiesJSON, Company[].class);
        return companies;
    }
```

First you need to make a template class that has a member field for each key in the json. E.g. `private String id` for the 'Id' key in the json you provided. In my example it is the Company class.

Next you make a new Gson object using `Gson gson = new Gson();` and use the `.fromJson` function supplying it both the Json array and the Object array *type* (which is of the form `MyClass[].class`).

Comment: If you want to deserialize a single object you can use `Company.class` which will return a single Company object as opposed to an array.

Answer (score 0):

First, your question is not to convert a JSON array without key. Second, there are many popular JSON libraries can achieve what you want such as `org.json`, `Jackson`, `Gson` and so on.
Here comes several examples:

1. With `org.json`, you can retrieve field values in a JSON array as follows:

```java
JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
System.out.println(jsonResponse.get(0).toString());
System.out.println("Id: " + jsonResponse.getJSONObject(0).get("Id"));
System.out.println("N : " + jsonResponse.getJSONObject(0).get("N"));
```

And the expected output should be:

> {"Fid":196,"CL":null,"Id":1290,"N":"Türkiye","EC":10,"SID":0}
> Id: 1290
> N : Türkiye

2. With `Jackson`, you can retrieve field values in a JSON array as follows:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
List<Map<String, Object>> jsonResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {});
System.out.println(jsonResponse.toString());
System.out.println("Id: " + jsonResponse.get(0).get("Id"));
System.out.println("N : " + jsonResponse.get(0).get("N"));
```

And the expected output should be:

> {Id=1290, N=Türkiye, Fid=196, EC=10, CL=null, SID=0}
> Id: 1290
> N : Türkiye
> 3. Furthermore, if you define a POJO as follows:

```java
class MyObject {
    private @JsonProperty("Id") int id;
    private @JsonProperty("N") String n;
    private @JsonProperty("Fid") int fid;
    private @JsonProperty("EC") int ec;
    private @JsonProperty("CL") int cl;
    private @JsonProperty("SID") int sid;

    //general getters, setters and toString
}
```

Then you can deserialize the JSON response to your POJO by:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<MyObject> jsonResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>() {});
System.out.println(jsonResponse.get(0).toString());
System.out.println("Id: " + jsonResponse.get(0).getId());
System.out.println("N : " + jsonResponse.get(0).getN());
```

And the expected output should be:

> MyObject{id=1290, n='Türkiye', fid=196, ec=10, cl=0, sid=0}
> Id: 1290
> N : Türkiye